# Is `make(chan _, _)` atomic?

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine

Is it thread-safe to modify the channel that a consumer is reading from?

Consider the following code:

```
func main(){
    channel     := make(chan int, 3)
    channel_ptr := &channel

    go supplier (channel_ptr)
    go consumer (channel_ptr)

    temp = *channel_ptr
    // Important bit
    *channel_ptr = make(chan int, 5)

    more := true
    for more{
        select {
            case msg := <-temp:
                *channel_ptr <- msg
            default:
                more = false
        }
    }
    // Block main indefinitely to keep the children alive
    <-make(chan bool)
}

func consumer(c *chan int){
    for true{
        fmt.Println(<-(*c))
    }
}

func supplier(c *chan int){
    for i :=0; i < 5; i ++{
        (*c)<-i
    }
}
```

If channels and `make` work the way that I want them to, I should get the following properties:

1. The program always outputs 0 1 2 3 4
2. The program will never panic from trying to read from a non-initialized channel (IE, the part I labelled `Important bit` is atomic)

From several test runs, this seems to be true, but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation and I'm worried about subtle race conditions.

### Update

Yeah, what I was doing doesn't work. This thread is probably buried at this point, but does anybody know how to dynamically resize a buffered channel?

Comment: calling `make` is neither atomic nor not atomic, it's just creating a new value. Writing that value to a variable is not atomic, because no read or writes are outside of `sync/atomic`.

Comment: @Alyss, the thing to ask yourself here is: what difference would it make? How would something try to modify the value of the variable during the course of the call to `make`? It can't, because you don't have a reference to it until `make` returns. If you don't have a reference to it, a reference can't be shared with a concurrent process, therefor atomicity is irrelevant.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not thread safe.

If you run with `-race` flag to use [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector), you'll see the bug:

```
$ run -race t.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c420086018 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /Users/kjk/src/go/src/github.com/kjk/go-cookbook/start-mysql-in-docker-go/t.go:14 +0x128

Previous read at 0x00c420086018 by goroutine 6:
  main.supplier()
      /Users/kjk/src/go/src/github.com/kjk/go-cookbook/start-mysql-in-docker-go/t.go:37 +0x51

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /Users/kjk/src/go/src/github.com/kjk/go-cookbook/start-mysql-in-docker-go/t.go:9 +0xb4
0
==================
1
2
3
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c420086018 by goroutine 6:
  main.supplier()
      /Users/kjk/src/go/src/github.com/kjk/go-cookbook/start-mysql-in-docker-go/t.go:37 +0x51

Previous write at 0x00c420086018 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /Users/kjk/src/go/src/github.com/kjk/go-cookbook/start-mysql-in-docker-go/t.go:14 +0x128

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /Users/kjk/src/go/src/github.com/kjk/go-cookbook/start-mysql-in-docker-go/t.go:9 +0xb4
==================
4
```

As a rule of thumb, you should never pass channel as a pointer. Channel already is a pointer internally.

Stepping back a bit: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

I guess there's a reason you're trying to pass a channel as a pointer. The pattern of using channels in Go is: you create it once and you pass it around as value. You don't pass a pointer to it and you never modify it after creation.

In your example the problem is that you have a shared piece of memory (memory address pointed to by `channel_ptr`) and you write to that memory in one thread while some other thread reads it. That's data race.

It's not specific to a channel, you would have the same issue if it was pointer to an int and two threads were modifying the value of an int.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a buffer resize on the channel. In the actual code, I have a slice of channels, and I want to be able to dynamically change the size of an individual buffer.

Comment: You can't do that. Don't try to hack around it, just accept the limitation that channels have fixed capacity. There is discussion about growable channels  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20352 but it won't happen in Go 1. You can use a queue and a signal if you really need unbounded size, but you loose the simplicity of channels.